# Time Study in Excel

Tags: excel

I am completing a time study and recording time in excel. I have numbers like 2.24, etc.. I am trying to add them and average them and I am getting numbers like 9.76 when I really want 10m and 16seconds. Any thoughts to fixing this? 
When I change the format to mm:ss it give me wild answers

Comment: If you enter **2.24** in a cell, are you trying to enter 2.24 seconds or 2 minutes 24 seconds ??

Comment: I find it odd and illogical that 9.76 would mean 9 mins and 76 secs. Normally a decimal value such as this would indicate 9 mins and 45.6 secs (76/100).

Comment: we have entered in times for various rounds and it was just doing a total sum   R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 Total Time Average Time
2.12 2.01 1.41 2.04 2.18   9.76         1.95

Comment: So 2.12 refers to 2 minutes and 12 seconds?

Comment: You need to enter in Excel as 0:02:12 then you can add quite nicely.

Comment: @Sinead is `9.76` a string or a number? I mean, is `.` your decimal separator? I need to know this

Answer (score 2):

If `9.76` is a **decimal number** and it's is in `A1`, then in `B1` you can use:

`=((A1-(ROUNDOWN(A1;0)))/0,6+(ROUNDOWN(A1;0)))/24`

Also, format of cell with formula must be hours (I've used `[hh]:mm:ss`)

Applying this, I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've done it in the following way: I used cell formatting, like `u:mm:ss` (in English locale, this might be `h:mm:ss` instead).

In one cell, I've put `0:2:24` (zero hours, two minutes, 24 seconds).
In the cell below, I've put `0:7:52`.

Adding both cells (inside a cell with the mentioned cell formatting) yielded `0:10:16`.

Answer (score 0):

=9.76 value(minutes)
=24*60 number of minutes in a day
=A1/A2 formatted as time

Will show 12:09:46. You can use `=MINUTE(A3)` to extract the minutes and `=SECOND(A3)`  for the seconds.

Actually if 9.76 means 9 minutes and 76 seconds, you'll need more formulas to extract the minutes and seconds then add them together. You can use `=Floor()` to get the integer. Subtract to find the .76 and multiply by 100 to get the number of seconds. Then divide by 60 to convert to minutes and add to the 9 whole mins. Now you have the number of mins which you can convert to a time value per the above.

EDIT:
You need to enter in Excel as 0:02:12 then you can add quite nicely. If you don't want to re-enter everything you can do this: `=VALUE("0:"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":"))` then add. Be sure to convert each individual value BEFORE adding otherwise you might get incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you but yes I mean 9 minutes 76 seconds so I need to get this to 10 minutes 16 seconds to be correct